# How many manuscripts of English Renaissance plays have survived?

Tags: textual-history, physical-books, english-renaissance-theater

During the English renaissance, plays were primarily written for performance and play manuscripts were usually not sold to a printer before the play had had a successful run in the theatre. A number of plays have survived in manuscript form, e.g. John Bale's [*King Johan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Johan) (rediscovered in the 1830s), Thomas Heywood's [*The Escapes of Jupiter*](http://cord.ung.edu/heywcali.html), Philip Massinger's [*The Parliament of Love*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Parliament_of_Love) and [*Believe as You List*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believe_as_You_List), [*The Second Maiden's Tragedy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Second_Maiden%27s_Tragedy) (contested authorship), Richard Brome's [*The English Moor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_English_Moor), [Sir Thomas More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Thomas_More_(play)) (collaborative work, possibly containing [Shakespeare's only surviving literary manuscript](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/shakespeares-handwriting-in-the-book-of-sir-thomas-more)). Apparently, some researchers also include Thomas Heywood's *The Captives* and Walter Mountfort's [*The Launching of the Mary*](http://digitalrenaissance.uvic.ca/doc/Launching_MS1/complete/) (see [Manuscripts and their Makers in the English Renaissance](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Manuscripts+and+their+Makers+in+the+English+Renaissance.-a0171658498)).

Some of these are part of the [British Library's **MS Egerton 1994**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Library,_MS_Egerton_1994), but not all the manuscripts in this collection are considered autographs.

So **how many English Renaissance plays (roughly from years the 1550 – 1625) have survived in manuscript form**? (These manuscripts can be in the handwriting of the original authors or contemporary copies.) I am not asking for an exhaustive list of plays but a source that discusses the (number of) surviving manuscripts.

Answer (score 4):

The [Catalogue of English Literary Manuscripts 1450–1700](http://www.celm-ms.org.uk) (CELM) has a comprehensive list of manuscripts from the period of interest. I sampled some of the authors and I estimate that the catalogue includes roughly 65 manuscripts of plays.

It's hard to be precise because it's not entirely clear what counts as a "play". Do extracts of plays count? Or musical settings of songs taken from plays? What about the librettos of operas, like John Dryden's [*The State of Innocence*](http://www.celm-ms.org.uk/authors/drydenjohn.html#DrJ-work-152)? Or the texts of masques, like Thomas Carew's [*The Visit of the Nine Goddesses*](http://www.celm-ms.org.uk/authors/carewthomas.html#CwT-work-133)? And of course, not all of the plays in the CELM are from your tighter period (1550–1625). But here are three examples which are:

- Thomas Dekker, [*The Welsh Embassador*](http://www.celm-ms.org.uk/authors/dekkerthomas.html#DkT-work-13). Copy, in a professional secretary hand, c.1624.
- Nathan Field, John Fletcher, and Philip Massinger, [*The Honest Man's Fortune*](http://www.celm-ms.org.uk/authors/beaumontfletcher.html#B_F-work-25). Copy in the hand of [Edward Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Knight_(King%27s_Men)), book-keeper and prompter of the King's Company, prepared for use as a prompt book, early 17th century.
- Thomas Middleton, [*A Game at Chess*](http://www.celm-ms.org.uk/authors/middletonthomas.html#MiT-work-9). Autograph manuscript, 1624.